# Android java development time of acceleration to

Tags: time, acceleration

How can I calculate the time of acceleration to 100kmh?
Well, I registered a location listener when the !location.hasSpeed() is true store the time of location into a variable. When the speed is reach of the given speed in this case 100km/h (27.77 m/s) I substract from the spped of location and the result I divide by 1000.

Here is the "pseudo code"

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location currentLoc) {

        // when stop reseted, when start reset again
        if (isAccelerationLoggingStarted) {
            if (currentLoc.hasSpeed() && currentLoc.getSpeed() > 0.0) {
                // dismiss the time between reset to start to move  
                startAccelerationToTime = (double) currentLoc.getTime();
            }
        }

        if (!currentLoc.hasSpeed()) {
            isAccelerationLoggingStarted = true;
            startAccelerationToTime = (double) currentLoc.getTime();
            acceleration100 = 0.0;
        }

        if (isAccelerationLoggingStarted) {
            if (currentLoc.getSpeed() >= 27.77) {
                acceleration100 = (currentLoc.getTime() - startAccelerationToTime) / 1000;
                isAccelerationLoggingStarted = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem i see here, is that *whenever* the device is moving, `startAccelerationToTime` is reset.  (The first `if` only checks whether there's movement; it doesn't check whether there's already a start time recorded.

I don't see where `isAccelerationLoggingStarted` is needed at all -- the speed, and the variables themselves, can be cleaned up a bit to make it clear what the next step should be.

Your pseudocode probably ought to look something like:

```
if speed is 0
    clear start time
else if no start time yet
    start time = current time
    clear acceleration time
else if no acceleration time yet, and if speed >= 100 mph 
    acceleration time = current time - start time
```

In Java, that'd look like...

```
long startTime = 0;
double accelerationTime = 0.0;

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location currentLoc) {

    // when stopped (or so slow we might as well be), reset start time
    if (!currentLoc.hasSpeed() || currentLoc.getSpeed() < 0.005) {
        startTime = 0;
    }

    // We're moving, but is there a start time yet?
    // if not, set it and clear the acceleration time
    else if (startTime == 0) {
        startTime = currentLoc.getTime();
        accelerationTime = 0.0;
    }

    // There's a start time, but are we going over 100 km/h?
    // if so, and we don't have an acceleration time yet, set it
    else if (accelerationTime == 0.0 && currentLoc.getSpeed() >= 27.77) {
        accelerationTime = (double)(currentLoc.getTime() - startTime) / 1000.0;
    }
}
```

Now, i'm not sure exactly how location listeners work, or how often they notify you when you're moving.  So this may only semi work.  In particular, `onLocationChanged` might not get called when you're not moving; you may need to request an update (perhaps via a "reset" button or something) or set certain params in order to trigger the stuff that happens when speed == 0.

Comment: Thanks. But comes up another problem.
How much time elapses from start of move to the GPS realize the moving and triggering an onLocationChange event.

Comment: I'd assume that depends partly on the device, and partly on the criteria you pass to `requestLocationUpdates`.

Comment: I passed zero to minTime and minDistance too